# How can I get the first and last part of one wordcombination using regex

Tags: regex, pcre

How can I get only the middle part of a combined name with PCRE regex?

name: `211103_TV_storyname_TYPE`

result: `storyname`

I have used this single line: `.(\d)+.(_TV_)`  to remove the first part: 211103_TV_

Another idea is to use `(_TYPE)$` but the problem is that I don´t have in all variations of names a space to declare a second word to use the ^ for the first word and $ for the second.

The variation of the combined name is fix for _TYPE and the *TV*.
The numbers are changing according to the date. And the storyname is variable.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `[^_]+(?=_[^_]+$)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D4gomC/1)

Answer (score 2):

You could match as least as possible chars after `_TV_` until you match `_TYPE`

```
\d_TV_\K.*?(?=_TYPE)
```

- `\d_TV_` Match a digit and `_TV_`
- `\K` Forget what is matched until now
- `.*?` Match as least as possible characters
- `(?=_TYPE)` Assert _TYPE to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0QxRaM/1)

Another option without a non greedy quantifier, and leaving out the digit at the start:

```
_TV_\K[^_]*+(?>_(?!TYPE)[^_]*)*(?=_TYPE)
```

- `_TV_` Match literally
- `\K[^_]*+` Forget what is matched until now and optionally match any char except `_`
- `(?>_(?!TYPE)[^_]*)*` Only allow matching `_` when not directly followed by TYPE
- `(?=_TYPE)` Assert _TYPE to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ed9wf4/1)

---

**Edit**

If you want to replace the 2 parts, you can use an alternation and replace with an empty string.

If it should be at the start and the end of the string, you can prepend `^` and append `$` to the pattern.

```
\b\d{6}_TV_|_TYPE\b
```

- `\b\d{6}_TV_` A word boundary, match 6 digits and `_TV_`
- `|` Or
- `_TYPE\b` Match `_TYPE` followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/06DxYU/1/)

Comment: do you need the `\d` at the start?

Comment: @Djave To get the same output, you can omit it. Is is part of the pattern that the OP tried, that is why a left matching a single digit in. You could also write `\b\d{6}_TV_\K.*?(?=_TYPE)` it depends on how specific the pattern should be.

Comment: Ah yes sorry you are quite right.

Comment: HI thanks for your options.
With Regex it is working fine. But with my tool that is using PCRE in a older version.
I have used `_TV_\K[^_]*+(?>_(?!TYPE)[^_]*)*(?=_TYPE)` 
for name: `211104_TV_STJHEU_TYPE`
Result is: `211104_TV__TYPE`
How i can get the opposite of the Result?

Comment: @datoby What is the name of the tool? That looks like a strange match, as this string `211104_TV__TYPE` is not part of `211104_TV_STJHEU_TYPE` I think you are replacing the match with an empty string correct?

Comment: @datoby If you want to remove the matches, you can use an alternation `\b\d{6}_TV_|_TYPE\b` and replace with an empty string. See https://regex101.com/r/06DxYU/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird The tool is a mediaassetmanagement with a renaming pattern. I have a Source Pattern where i put the code. And a target pattern with $5 (5 Matches)  or $0 keep original. Then there is a test pattern area. I put in the Name. And get directly the result. So beginning from my code to remove the date yymmdd and _TV_  it bring me the same result like your code.   storyname_TYPE i see in Regex different results. Are there versions between?

Comment: @datoby I am not familiar with the tool. Do you know if there is some documentation available online? Or maybe some screenshots on how the renaming works?

Comment: @Thefourthbird i added a screenshot in a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following regex, this creates one capturing group which contains matched values in it.

```
.*?_TV_([^_]*)(?=_TYPE)
```

***OR***(adding a small variation of above solution with fourth bird's nice suggestion), following is without lazy match `.*?` unlike above:

```
_TV_([^_]*)(?=_TYPE)
```

[Here is the Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/LuOvkB/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
.*?_      ##Using Lazy match to match till 1st occurrence of _ here.
TV_       ##Matching TV_ here.
([^_]*)   ##Creating 1st capturing group which has everything before next occurrence of _ here.
(?=_TYPE) ##Making sure previous values are followed by _TYPE here.
```

Comment: HI 
thanks for your code. I have used this snippet: `.*?_TV_([^_]*)(?=_TYPE)` for 
name `211102_TV_UTHERK_TYPE`
Result is with my tool using PCRE:  `UTHERK_TYPE`
Any recommendations? 
Thanks

Comment: @datoby, ok how about using `_TV_([^_]*)(?=_TYPE)` once?

Comment: `211102_TV_UTHERK_TYPE`
is with `_TV_([^_]*)(?=_TYPE)`    and Target Pattern: `$4` 
`211102_TYPE`

with Target Pattern: `$1`
`211102UTHERK_TYPE`

with Target Pattern: `$5`
`211102_TYPE`

it is an older tool. Another idea to get only storyname ?